# how to distinguish touch vs mouse event from SetWindowsHookEx in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have found a way to listen to the mouse event, but what I really want is the touch event not mouse. They seem to share the same code. Is there any way to tell if the event was touch and not mouse? Thanks

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc (int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    private LowLevelMouseProc _proc = hookProc;

    private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public void SetHook()
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _proc, hInstance, 0);
    }

    public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Param: " + wParam + ", CODE: " + code + "\n");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetHook();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lParam` argument of your `hookProc` callback is a pointer to an `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`. It contains a *very* poorly documented `dwExtraInfo` variable, which tells you whether it was generated from a touch.

If all of the bits in `0xFF515700` are set in `dwExtraInfo`, then the callback was invoked in response to a touch:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public POINT pt;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint flags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

const int TOUCH_FLAG = 0xFF515700;
bool IsTouch(IntPtr lParam)
{
    MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookData = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, 
        typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
    uint extraInfo = (uint)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt32();
    if ((extraInfo & TOUCH_FLAG) == TOUCH_FLAG)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you are the best!!

Comment: say I have more than 2 fingers on the screen moving at the same time, am I able to print out the coords of two separate touches?