# Capture touch input on the screen in windows device

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, touch, windows-10-desktop

Is there any way to capture touch input on the screen (outside application frame) in windows device?

I'm working on a WPF application and can retrieve the touch input if it only occurs within the application frame. Also, is there a way to register the touch input even when the application is minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in method of the WPF framework that lets you listen for input outside of the application. If you want to do that, you'll have to get into p/invoke territory.

Specifically you'll need to create a [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks). You'll want to look at the [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) method and either the [`WH_MOUSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_mouse) or [`WH_MOUSE_LL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_mouse_ll) hooks.

Since you're dealing with touch inputs, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45473876/5086631) might have some useful information for you:

> The `lParam` argument of your `hookProc` callback is a pointer to an [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct). It contains a *very* poorly documented `dwExtraInfo` variable, which tells you whether it was generated from a touch.
>
> If all of the bits in `0xFF515700` are set in `dwExtraInfo`, then the callback was invoked in response to a touch.